Proxy not working in Chrome and getting error
I have opened the chrome with proxy command line switch
--proxy-server="https=http://{proxyipaddress}:{proxyport}"
but I am facing "(failed)net::ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED". But the same proxy is working in Firefox.
I have disabled the Proxy server at LAN settings level and also disabled chrome extensions.
Tried accessing mutliple websites but still getting same error. I have tested the chrome and firefox on same Network but still facing error in chrome where as it is working in firefox.
What additional settings/configurations required to open chrome with proxy not at system LAN settings level?


Maybe you didn't exit all chrome processes before starting this command line? Verify it in chrome://version 2) Use chrome://net-export to see what happens internally.


There is only single chrome process running and file exported through chrome://net-export didnot showing up any concrete failures to understand.

Chrome always runs 5-10 processes. Try checking the command line in chrome://version.
